# Dificuldades com arredondamento usando BigDecimal

Tags: java

Escrevi o seguinte método:

```
public static double round(double value, int scale) {
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
    bd.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd.doubleValue();
}
```

Realizo a chamada:

```
round(72.46976811594203, 2)
```

E obtenho a seguinte saída:

> 72.46976811594203

Gostaria que fosse retornado 72.47, já que estou arredondando para duas casas decimais. Onde está o erro?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

BigDecimal é imutável, logo, quando você chama o método `setScale()` ele não altera o valor da variável `bd`, ele **retorna** o valor arredondado, entretanto como não há nenhuma variável recebendo o valor de retorno ele simplesmente é jogado ao vento, ou seja, o valor arredondado nunca é utilizado.

Uma possível solução é assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(round(72.46976811594203, 2));
}
public static double round(double value, int scale) {
    BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal(value);
    BigDecimal bd2 = bd1.setScale(scale, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
    return bd2.doubleValue();
}
```

Imprime:

> 72.47

Perceba que o valor retornado pelo `setScale()` é armazenado em uma nova variável, e o valor dessa variável é então retornado pelo método `round()`.

Referência: [BigDecimal - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int))

Comment: Realmente cometi um grande equivoco. Não notei que o setScale() retornava o resultado. Grato!